# JavaFX export without VM options

Tags: java, maven, javafx

Let me start off by saying this question is very similar to this one:

[JavaFX Export and VM arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58936763/javafx-export-and-vm-arguments)

I've seen this question and it has helped me a lot further. However, I am quite new to Maven.
I'm trying to export my maven project, which uses both JavaFX and JMTP, to an executeable jar file. However, after running `mvn clean package`, running the jar file (with dependecies) gives the following error:

> Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

This is my `pom.xml` file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestMavenFX</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>in-project</id>
            <name>JMTP-in-project</name>
            <url>file://${project.basedir}\libs</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics </artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml </artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jmtp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmtp-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>12</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.example.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>main.java.org.example.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>
                                main.java.org.example.App
                            </mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>main.java.org.example.App</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Is there anyone who could help with this? I would like to use this instead of a `.bat` file to run a command to actually run the JAR file, but I'm quite stuck.

Comment: Not Maven-specific, but... Related Q&As: [How to deploy a JavaFX 11 Desktop application with a JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453212/), [JavaFX 11 : Create a jar file with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52569724/), [Maven Shade JavaFX runtime components are missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653836/), and [Package a non-modular JavaFX application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54063041/).

Comment: Thank you! Using the information from these links i managed to get it working!